# 2 rotating objects opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a rotating object rotating about 0,0,0. I now want another object to rotate about the other object. so kind of like the earth rotating around the sun and then the moon rotating around the earth.
I am not sure how to go about this.

```
void earth(){
glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(anglee, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.0,20,0);
    glutSolidSphere(0.8,50,50);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(anglee, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(0.0,20.0,8);
    glutSolidSphere(0.4,50,50);
glPopMatrix();
anglee+=4.0f;
}
```

I have got the first rotation correct, but i am not sure how to go about the second rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint.. do this in your display callback function:

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(10,10,10, 0,0,0, 0,1,0);

    /* current position is by default the origin */

    //draw sun
    glutSolidSphere(1,100,100);

    //draw planet
    glRotated(angle1,0,1,0);        //rotates position by angle1
    glTranslated(0,0,5);            //translates position by sun-planet distance
    glutSolidSphere(0.7,100,100);   //draw planet at this new position

    //draw moon
    glRotated(angle2,0,1,0);        //rotates position by angle1+angle2
    glTranslated(0,0,2);            //translates position by planet-moon distance
    glutSolidSphere(0.3,100,100);   //draw moon at this new position

    glutSwapBuffers();

    angle1 += 0.2;
    angle2 += 0.2;
    if(angle1 > 360) angle1 = 0;
    if(angle2 > 360) angle2 = 0;
}
```

Try commenting some lines from both the draw planet and moon parts and see the difference, will help you understand it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have in your **Second** Rotation :

```
glRotatef(anglee, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Is that you haven't specified NoRotation Axis !!

Try:

```
glRotatef(anglee, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

to rotate around **Y Axis** !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudocode:

Declare a time float.

Increment it by a small value like .01 on your update/draw loop

do a Math.cos(time) * (your desired radius) for the transform X value and Math.sin(time) * (your desired radius) for the transform Y value. This will result in orbiting based on the rate of time progression around zero.

If you need to have it offset by the position of your "center object" then just add the translation of the first object to each translation axis.

Comment: I don't think that doing the Math on the CPU would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is transforming the 2 spheres both abosutly in space. What you need to do is to do the positioning of the moon relative the position of the earth -> don't do a glPopMatrix() between drawing the earth and the moon. By doing so you are kind of resetting the opengl transformation matrix.

I would try it as follows:

1. draw the moon at 0/0/0
2. transform the moon to the orbit around 0/0/0
3. draw the earth at 0/0/0
4. transform the earth to the orbit around the sun

So everything can be done on the GPU ...

PS: I have not tried your code. So it's possible that some further changes to the code have to be done in order to work as expected ...